# How extract data from a site which does not provide a restful service?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, web, web-scraping

It includes login into the site too.
Trying get data from the site which shows analytic of some client data. If my app has show this data, I would need to:

1. Login to the site.
2. Go to a url
3. Get the data from url page.

What are the ways of achieving it?
 Is it what can be done by web scraping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would use scraping for this.  You had node.js in your keywords.  If you're planning on using Node.js for this then you should check out [Phantom.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/phantom).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, scraping would be a solution to this. If you are using Ruby then look at something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse and then scrape the content from within the HTML of the various pages.